# Ruby oneliner check if multiple lines exist in a file

Tags: ruby

What I want to do is to create a Ruby oneliner to check if multiple lines exist in a file.  Return a 0 return code if found otherwise 1.

For example if I have a file named /tmp/foo with the following content.

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
```

If the search string is 'one\ntwo\nthree' then it would return 0.
If the search string is 'one\two\four' then it would return 1.

I found a bunch of examples online such as the following but those are mainly for search/replace and search/print.  I am not sure how to massage it to do what I want.

```
ruby -i -e 'puts gets(nil).gsub(/${line}/,\"\")' ${file}
ruby -ne 'print -f ~/<regex>/' <file>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. There may be shorter:

```
ruby -e "exit(gets(nil) =~ %r{${line}} ? 0 : 1)" ${file}
```

Example call:

```
ash@autumn ~ $ cat sample 
one
two
three
four
five
ash@autumn ~ $ ruby -e 'exit(gets(nil) =~ %r{one\ntwo\nthree} ? 0 : 1)' sample ; echo $?
0
ash@autumn ~ $ ruby -e 'exit(gets(nil) =~ %r{one\ntwo\nfour} ? 0 : 1)' sample ; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read(filename).include?("one\ntwo\nthree") ? 0 : 1

doc = <<END
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
END

filename = 'data'
File.write(filename, doc)

File.read(filename).include?("one\ntwo\nthree") ? 0 : 1 # => 0
File.read(filename).include?("one\ntwo\nfour")  ? 0 : 1 # => 1
```

From the command line:

```
ruby -e 'File.read("data").include?("one\ntwo\nthree") ? 0 : 1' # => 0
```